# What design pattern should I use for import, update, export

Tags: c#, design-patterns, code-quality

I need to create a simple payments validator. On the following class diagram, I tried to present the model of payments. As you can see, each payment type inherits from Payments class.

[image: Payments diagram]

Now I want to work with these payments but hide the details so the user can only access what he needs. And those things are are:

`Load` payments from path and return list of payments

`Save` payments to path

`Update` input payments list and return updated list

I am not sure if the way I am doing it is correct.

My idea would be to use Facade design pattern, so `PaymentsModel` class which would contain following methods should be created:

```
public class PaymentsModel
{

    IList<ToBePaidPaymentsDto>  GetToBePaidPayments(string path){
         return new IList<ToBePaidPaymentsDto>();
    }

    IList<DonePaymentsDto>  GetDonePayments(string path){
         return new IList<DonePaymentsDto>();
    }

    IList<MissedPaymentsDto>  GetMissedPayments(string path){
         return new IList<MissedPaymentsDto>();
    }

    ...

}
```

Then create abstract class:

```
public abstract class Payments<T> 
{
    protected string Delimiter {get; private set;}
    protected int NumberOfHeaders {get; private set;}

    public abstract IList<T> LoadRecords(string path);

    public abstract IList<T> UpdateRecords(IList<T> records);

    public void SaveRecords(string path, DataGridViewRowCollection records)
    {
    }
```

}

where T is Data Transfer Object depending on the type of payments, so:

`ToBePaidPayments` class would use `ToBePaidPaymentsDto`

`DonePayments` class would use `DonePaymentsDto`

as presented below

```
public class PaymentsToBePaid : Payments<IcsToBePaidPaymentDto> {

    public override IList<IcsToBePaidPaymentDto> LoadRecords(string path){

        return null;
    }


    public override  IList<IcsToBePaidPaymentDto> UpdateRecords(IList<IcsToBePaidPaymentDto> records){

        return null;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class PaymentsDone : Payments<IcsDonePaymentDto>
{
    public override IList<IcsDonePaymentDto> LoadRecords(string path){

        return null;
    }

    public override IList<IcsDonePaymentDto> UpdateRecords(IList<IcsDonePaymentDto> records){

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, my final question is - am I doing this correctly? Am I applying correct design pattern and am I applying it correctly? 
Thank you for advice.

Comment: First off the bat, why do you have 3 objects when a "PaymentStatus" enumeration might suffice?  Or do you indeed need 3 separate "queues"?

Comment: @Moo-Juice I decided to use different classes because the way reading from file is done - each type of payment is composed of different set of columns from csv which usualy do not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment that payments have different fields based on their status (and I will therefore assume this is an issue because of database tables), then What I'd do is implement a CsvReader class that has a generic-type argument, that maps Csv fields to the POCO in question.  Therefore you'd write a single Csv Importer, and that can then be used to import data regardless of what class you throw at it.

Similarly, you can write a CsvExporter class that does the same thing.  Write once, use everywhere.

Some comments:

1. Remove the `Dto` extension.  We know what a payment is, it can potentially be used in many places (the database, the Csv File, business logic).  `Dto` is relevant in a single, specific scenario.
2. Consider changing `Todo` to `Pending`.

Comment: Thanks for comments, but I do not really understand the first part of your answer. If I got it correctly, you are suggesting to move reading of file to a distinct class, but it is still unclrear for me how to work with parsed data further on when I have to do some updates on the each type of payments...

Comment: @Macin, the idea is that your Reader/Writer classes are *generic*, they are not tied to any particular class.  Given a generic-type-parameter, they can read or write *any* class.  So you'd read them in, perform whatever operations you want to - on first class POCOS, and then write them back again (if that is your intent).

Comment: May I ask you to write some pseudo code? Maybe your idea is much better than what I did but I just can't imagine it easily enough